# 2D Char array Minesweeper game loop

Tags: java, text, char, multidimensional-array, minesweeper

I'm a Comp Sci student taking intro to Comp Sci. Right now we are working on an end of the year project which is a text based minesweeper game using java. For the first part we are suppose to make a representation of a 5x5 minesweeper board as a 2 D char array and manually add bomb locations and then update the numbers that indicate the neighboring bombs.Then we create a second representation of the board that will represent whether or not the cell has been revealed.

After that we need to write the following methods:

**print Board(char[][] board, Boolean[][] is Revealed)**: prints a Minesweeper board to screen in text form. Keep in mind, that the printed board should reflect which cells have already been revealed.

**reveal Cell(int row, int col, Boolean[][] game board, char[][] answers board)**: Appropriately modifies the state array when a cell is to be revealed while also determining how to reveal the surrounding blank spaces according to the rules of Minesweeper.

Then we have to write a main game loops that incorporates both of these methods while checking to see if the player won or lost.

I've already done the print board and the reveal cell method, I just need to make a game board and game loop to test it.

We are not aloud to use classes or modules outside java.lang (do not import any libraries).

Here is my code:
   public static void main(String[] args) {

```
char[][]answerboard= {{'B', '1', '0', '1', 'B'},
                      {'1', '1', '1', '2', '1'},
                      {'0', '1', 'B', '2', '1'},
                      {'1', '1', '1', '2', 'B'},
                      {'B', '1', '0', '1', '1'}};
// Initialized answer board: This is the board that shows what is inside each cell. I need to create a second 2d array representation that shows which cells have been revealed.
int row , col ;
for (row = 0; row < answerboard.length; row++){
     for (col = 0; col < answerboard[1].length; col++)
     System.out.print(answerboard[row][col]);
     System.out.println();

    }


}
  public static void printBoard(char[][] board, boolean[][] isRevealed) 
    {
        for(int i=0; i < board.length; i++)
        {
                for(int j=0; j<=board[0].length; j++)
                {
                        if(isRevealed[i][j]=true)
                        System.out.print(board[i][j]+" ");//prints hidden char
                        else
                        if(isRevealed[i][j]= false)
                        System.out.print("- ");
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
        }
 }

    public static void revealCell(int row, int col, boolean[][] gameboard, char[][]answersboard) {
    System.out.println(row + " " + col);
    if(row < 0|| row >=answersboard.length ||col < 0|| col > answersboard[0].length){
        System.out.println("bad input");
        return;
    }

    if(answersboard[row][col] == 'B'){
        gameboard[row][col] = answersboard[row][col];
        return;
    }
    if(answersboard[row][col] == '1'||answersboard[row][col] == '2'){
        gameboard[row][col] = answersboard[row][col];
        return;
    }

    if(answersboard[row][col] == '0'){
        gameboard[row][col] = answersboard[row][col];
        for(int i = row-1; i <= row +1; i++){
            for(int j = col-1; j<= col +1;j++){
                revealCell(i,j, gameboard, answersboard);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what your question is... Yeah doesn't look like you asked one.

Just a suggestion, Perhaps it might be a good idea to make a `MineSweeperBoard` class, and have these all be public non-static methods of the class. Teachers always like to see first year students getting a handle on Object Orients programming and be able to pull classes out of problems.

Edit. Also you probably shouldn't have the `System.out.println(...)` stuff in your methods that are supposed to be working on the state of the gameboard. This is creating side effects and breaks the one task per method idea. Rather have whatever method is handling the input/output decide if the input is appropriate prior to calling this method. Ideally you would have these methods throw `IllegalArgumentExceptions` if someone does give bad data to a method, but you may not have covered that yet.

Good Luck on the rest of your project and exams!!

Comment: What I'm trying to do is incorporate my initial board, a second revealed sate representation and the print board and reveal cell method into a game loop that ask the user for the coordinates of the cell they want to reveal  and checks to see if the player won or lost. But I just can't figure it out.